# Can’t reboot macOS machine: Forgot the admin password and can’t find the firmware password

Tags: mac

I forgot the admin password and I tried to reboot my macOS machine won't reboot. I can’t find firmware password. I tried to use the `fcsk-fy` to reboot failed. Might be a hardware issue?

My system is:

- **macOS Version**: 10.9.5
- **Processor**: 3.4GHZ intel corei5
- **Memory**: GB1600MHZDDR3
- **Startup Disk**: Untitled

Please help I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

On older Macs you can reset the firmware password. Newer Macs you have to take to Apple with proof of ownership.

This from [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/78792/How+do+I+reset+the+firmware+password+on+my+MacBook+Pro)

> Have you tried this? Feedback from the comments in the article says it
>   works:
>
> Add or remove a stick of RAM. Obviously if you have one stick in, add
>   one and if you have two in remove one.
>
> Power on the Mac and immediately press and hold command-option-P-R.
>
> The system will restart with the ‘bong' noise; allow it to do this 3
>   times. On the third ‘bong’ you can let go of the keys.
>
> The machine will now boot with a cleared password and reset
>   PRAM/NVRAM.
>
> You can then shut down the machine and reconfigure the RAM
>   configuration as you want it.